# Was ist das Gegenteil von »Meine Wenigkeit«?

Tags: word-usage, idiom

Es gibt ja das Sprichwort (oder wie man sowas nennt) »meine Wenigkeit«, eher im gehobenen Sprachgebrauch.

Was ist das Gegenteil? »Meine Vielzahl« oder so?

Comment: Was verstehst du hier konkret als Gegenteil? »Meine Wenigkeit« ist eine unterwürfige selbstbezeichnung, die früher vielleicht in Gesprächen mit rang- oder sozial höher gestellten Personen angebracht war, heutzutage aber eher ironisch oder sarkastisch verwendet wird. Meinst du als Gegenteil nun eine hochmütige Selbstbezeichnung oder eine Bezeichnung des Gesprächspartners, die seine Unterwürfigkeit andeuten soll?

Comment: Ironisch hab ich schon des Öfteren *meine Vielheit* benützt. Ich rate hiermit explizit davon ab, das als Gegenteil zu sehen, denn es passt semantisch nicht ;)

Comment: Es gibt nicht unbedingt zu allem ein Gegenteil. Zu einem *Pinguin* z.B. auch nicht...

Comment: Zu manchem gibt es auch mehrere Gegenteile, z.B. zu _wegfahren_.

Comment: @tofro: … _Eisbär_…‽ ó.Ò

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Meine Wenigkeit" dient als Marker, der die eigene Unbedeutendheit gegenüber dem Gesprächspartner ausdrückt. Das Gegenteil ist also der *pluralis maiestatis*:

> Wir erlauben Ihnen, unsere Krone zurechtzurücken.

(Wie es sich trifft, hat die Konstruktion also wirklich mit einer Mehrzahl zu tun. Ob das Zufall ist oder Methode, müssen Psychologen beurteilen.)

Answer (score 5):

"Meine Wenigkeit" ist wohl eher eine Redewendung oder eine Floskel.

Ausgehend davon, dass sie dafür gedacht ist den Sprecher als unwichtiger darzustellen denn den Angesprochenen, denke ich dass "Eure Hoheit/Ehrwürdigkeit/Erhabenheit" und vergleichbare Wendungen am ehesten dem Gegenteil entsprechen. (Dabei ist zu beachten, dass die meisten dieser Anspracheformen auf einen sehr speziellen Personenkreis angewandt werden.)

Comment: Kommt mir nicht ganz passend vor. Wenigkeit wird doch hauptsächlich als Eigenbezeichnung, während Hoheit, Ehrwürdigkeit oder Erhabenheit als Anrede verwendet.

Comment: Ah, ich habe nicht nur die Bedeutung verändert, sondern auch die Bezugsperson. In dem Fall wäre der _pluralis majestis_ passender, oder?

Comment: Der Begriff "Gegenteil" ist ja nicht eindeutig. Man kann "Euer Hochwürden" durchaus als Gegenteil von "meine Wenigkeit" ansehen.